# Android Virtual Device using Blue Stacks or Andy

Tags: android, android-emulator

can someone help me out, I do not have hardware acceleration for the Vyper/Haxm software. So, I am trying to use BlueStacks or Andy as my virtual device emulators. But How do I get them to connect with the Android virtual device manager?

Answer (score 2):

Run this application(blueStacks etc). This application will give you already have a device or you will be prompted to create. then run the virtual application from a new device while the compiler. I think genymotion use.